# Amcharts "TypeError: this.chart.zoomToDates is not a function"

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

I'm trying to follow [this](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/5ad2f052d8e8e1c6e381179de9667a80) primer to create external zoom control.

I have 3 buttons

```
  <v-btn v-on:click="showPeriod('1 month')">1 month</v-btn>
  <v-btn v-on:click="showPeriod('3 month')">3 month</v-btn>
  <v-btn v-on:click="showPeriod('6 month')">6 month</v-btn>
```

and the `eventListener` `showPeriod`

```
  showPeriod: function(period) {
    console.log("Periods", this.periods)
    if (period != 'All'){
      this.changeDataZoom(this.periods[period])
    }
    else {
      //Logic fot 'ALL' period
    }
  },

  changeDataZoom: function (rawPeriod) {
    let regex = /([0-9]{2,4}[\-][0-9]{2}[\-][0-9]{2}).*?/g
    let periods = []

    rawPeriod.match(regex).forEach(function (period) {
      periods.push(moment(period,"YYYY-MM-D").format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
    })

    //Periods ["2018-01-26", "2018-07-27"]
    this.chart.zoomToDates(periods[0], periods[1])
  },
```

But when I trying to call `this.chart.zoomToDates` I get an error  "TypeError: this.chart.zoomToDates is not a function"

I also tried to convert string to date using `AmCharts.stringToDate` but it didn't help me either. 
[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/9jz98r2x3o) to reproduce an error

P.S. I know about `periods` property - but in this case 1 month is not actually the calendar month, so I need to specify dates manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That codepen uses **serial** chart and you're using **stock** chart.

Serial chart has method [zoomToDates](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmSerialChart#zoomToDates)

> zoomToDates(start, end) 
>   start - start date, Date object \ end - end date, Date object

Stock chart has method [zoom](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#zoom)

> zoom(startDate, endDate) 
>   startDate, endDate - **Date objects**.

So, you need something like:

```
changeDataZoom: function (rawPeriod) {
    let regex = /([0-9]{2,4}[\-][0-9]{2}[\-][0-9]{2}).*?/g
    let periods = []

    rawPeriod.match(regex).forEach(function (period) {
      periods.push(moment(period,"YYYY-MM-D").format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
    })

    //Periods ["2018-01-26", "2018-07-27"]
    this.chart.zoom(new Date(periods[0]), new Date(periods[1]))
}
```